# Output forEach result in the console?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this command on the mongo cli, but I am not getting any results:

```
db.files.find({
    state: 4,
    created : {
            '$gte': ISODate("2017-01-18T00:00:00.000Z"),
            '$lte': ISODate("2017-01-19T00:00:00.000Z")
    }
}).forEach( function (o) {
    db.users.find({"id": ObjectId(o.user)},{"username": 1}).pretty();
});
```

How do I output the username in the cli?

```
db.users.find({},{'id':1, 'username':1}).pretty();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5489b6abe4b0e66fc6491c85"),
    "username" : "user@domain.tld"
}

db.files.find({ }, {'id': 1, 'user': 1} ).pretty();
{ "_id" : "--M17HJrR1m1svX6GZS-YQ", "user" : "56bfe199fe6cc47d0c2f8781" }
{ "_id" : "--bnG8eJTfiYE08xjDphmQ", "user" : "56c477a9da1173ce065abfbf" }
{ "_id" : "-0G2Q5fQQTCJhqEWjVkQYw", "user" : "57388a9b9ef0e2201245b265" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing that `user` field in the files collection is a string, not `ObjectId`, you need to create a list of `ObjectId`s i.e. map the `user` id strings to an array of `ObjectId`s that you can query the `users` collection with.

For example, the following uses the **[`distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)** method with a second query argument on both collections to produce arrays that you can query the references with. The final results will print to console the `usernames`:

```
var userIds = db.files.distinct("user", {
    "state": 4,
    "created" : {
        "$gte": ISODate("2017-01-18T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "$lte": ISODate("2017-01-19T00:00:00.000Z")
    }
}).map(function(id) { return ObjectId(id); } );
db.users.distinct("username", {"_id": { "$in": userIds } }).forEach(printjson);
```

---

If the user field is an `ObjectId`, then use the aggregation framework's **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** operator as follows:

```
db.files.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "state": 4,
            "created": {
                "$gte": ISODate("2017-01-18T00:00:00.000Z"),
                "$lte": ISODate("2017-01-19T00:00:00.000Z")
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "users",
            "localField": "user",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "userList"
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "user": {
                "$arrayElemAt": ["$userList", 0]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "username": "$user.username"
        }
    }
]).map(function(doc) { return doc.username; }).forEach(printjson);
```

Comment: is not reurning the username, but the user id?

Comment: i just get `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

isn't that should be "_id" instead of "id"

```
db.files.find({
    state: 4,
    created : {
            '$gte': ISODate("2017-01-18T00:00:00.000Z"),
            '$lte': ISODate("2017-01-19T00:00:00.000Z")
    }
}).forEach( function (o) {
    db.users.find({"_id": ObjectId(o.user)},{"username": 1}).pretty();
});
```

Also I think you can get all the id and then call in operators too

```
var userIds = [];
db.files.find({
        state: 4,
        created : {
                '$gte': ISODate("2017-01-18T00:00:00.000Z"),
                '$lte': ISODate("2017-01-19T00:00:00.000Z")
        }
    },{user:1}).forEach( function (o) {
        userIds.push(new ObjectId(o.user));
    });
    db.users.find({"_id": {$in : userIds},{"username": 1}).pretty();
```

P.S - Chridam approach is more favorable than any of these.